# Как проверить ячейку БД на наличие null?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Имеется БД со столбцами (к примеру) id | ст1 | ст2, записываем в ст2, к примеру, 
число 4, тогда получается запись 1 | null | 4. В активности есть TextView в который по коду записывается последнее значение столбца ст1 , во время запуска активности обращаемся к БД и делаем запрос только ст1, но курсор обращается к значению null и крашит выполнение, как проверку выполнить? если записей не было то проверяется просто через

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst)
{
    textview.setText(получаем текст из БД);
}
else
{
    textview.setText("рандом текст");
}
```

а вот как быть когда в этой нужной ячейке null никак не могу понять

Comment: if (cursor.moveToFirst != null) ?

Comment: Разные способы решения проблемы есть. Можно отфильтровать в запросе строки содержащие null. Можно проверить полученное из курсора значение на null в условном выражении. Можно получить значение в Optional. И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @WorkappWorkapp метод `cursor.moveToFirst` возвращает `true` или `false` и `null` вернуть никак не может.  Так же результат этого метода указывает на то, смог ли курсор переместиться на первую запись в результате или нет. К значениям в столбцах этот метод не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки значения столбца на `null` используйте метод [isNull](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull(int))

```
Cursor cursor = ...
if(!cursor.isNull(columnIndex)){
    // Получаем значение столбца по этому индексу
}
```

Comment: спасибо, это то что нужно!